# How to solve the following problem in the shortest possible execution time (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm

**Input:**

Given an array of integers T = [t0, t1, t2, ... tk] representing a row where each element is the maximum waiting time. And an array E = [e0, e1, e2, ... ei] representing all expiration times. Finally, it is given an integer K that represents the maximum size of a container.

**Problem:**

For each expiration time E, it is necessary to obtain the position of the last element T that was able to enter the container of size K. Each waiting time in T must be greater than or equal to the expiration time E to be able to enter the container. If there are not enough elements in T to reach container size k, then return 0 for that element E.
The arrays E and T can have size <=100000. In cases they are too long, the algorithm creates a Time Limit Exceeded situation.

**Example:**

Input:

*K = 2; T = [1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 6]; E = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]*

Output:

*Kth = [2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0]*

**Explanation:**

1. In E[0], the expiration time is 1, so the 2nd in row T will be the last to enter the container, so Kth[0] = 2nd;
2. In E[1], the expiration time is 2, so the 3rd in row T will be the last to enter the container since the 1st element has expired, so Kth[1] = 3rd;
3. In E[2], the expiration time is 3, so the 3rd in row T will be the last to enter the container since the 1st element has expired, so Kth[2] = 3rd;
4. In E[3], the expiration time is 4, so the 3rd in row T will be the last to enter the container since the 1st element has expired, so Kth[3] = 3rd;
5. In E[4], the expiration time is 5, in this case almost all elements of T except the last one have expired, however, as it was not possible to complete the container, it must return position 0, therefore Kth[4] = 0;
6. And so on for E[5] and E[6].

**Possible solution (but has Low Performance when arrays E and T has a large size):**

1. For each element E, search in array T for elements that are greater than or equal to the expiration time E.
2. Count all the elements found in step 1, if the total is equal to K, the last position read is the Kth element. Else return 0, because there will be no kth element.
3. Repeat step 1 for all elements of E.

```java
public static int[] kth(int k, int[] t, int[] e) {
        int[] kth = new int[e.length];
        
        if (k > t.length)
            return kth;
        
        Arrays.sort(e);
        int c = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {            
            for (int j = 0; j < t.length; j++) {
                if (t[j] >= e[i])
                    c++;
                
                if (c >= k) {
                    kth[i] = j + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            if (c < k)
                kth[i] = 0;
            
            c = 0;
        }
        
        return kth;
}
```

```java
/*If you want to test*/
public static void main(String args[]) {

       

        int[] p = new int[7];

        p[0]=1;
        p[1]=4;
        p[2]=4;
        p[3]=3;
        p[4]=1;
        p[5]=2;
        p[6]=6;

        int[] q = new int[7];

        q[0]=1;
        q[1]=2;
        q[2]=3;
        q[3]=4;
        q[4]=5;
        q[5]=6;
        q[6]=7;

        kthPerson(2, p, q);


}
 /*You will get 
2
3
3
3
0
0
0. Which is desired result but when the input is really large I get the java heap error*/
```

I need ideas or suggestions to solve the problem in the shortest possible execution time.